# Connection between MySQL Event and Table

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a MySQL Event but it relates with table record id,
so when that record is deleted at that time this MySQL Event should be deleted.

It worked with my code but what if record is directly deleted from phpMyAdmin?

Trying this scenario, the Event is not deleted and record does not exist. So an error occured.

```
$this->db->insert("invoice", $data);
        $last = $this->db->insert_id();
        if ($last)
            $str = $this->db->last_query();
        $this->db->query("SET GLOBAL event_scheduler =  'ON'");

        $this->db->query("CREATE EVENT rec" . $last . " ON SCHEDULE 
EVERY 1 MONTH STARTS DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL '0:01' HOUR_MINUTE) 
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE DO $str");
```

How can I overcome this problem? I Heard that i can use a trigger but How?

Comment: Yes, you should use TRIGGER on delete to remove the associated event...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a trigger like this:

```
SET @ename:='rec';
SET @sql_text = concat('CREATE TRIGGER delete_invoice_event AFTER DELETE on TABLE FOR EACH ROW BEGIN DROP EVENT IF EXISTS ', @ename ,'old.id END');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_text;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

You have to use PREPARE statement, because your event name is dynamic, based on the deleted record id that would be accessible by old.id